# no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.16299 in the manifest list entries error on pulling hello-world image

Tags: docker, windows-10, windows-container

I've installed docker on windows 10 and configured for windows container. I'm not able to switch to linux container. it is throwing some exception.

When I pull hello-world image it is giving "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.16299 in the manifest list entries" message. What does this error mean? I tried experimental mode too. This solution I found on stack overflow. I've also tried to reinstall docker for windows but no luck.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "no matching manifest" error happens when that particular image could not be found (e.g., `openjdk:8` exists but `openjdk:69` would cause that error to be thrown because it doesn't exist).

The `hello-world` image *does* exist on Docker Hub, but not for certain computers (e.g., your Windows AMD). The alternate `hello-world` image to be used on such computers is `docker/surprise` (run `docker run --rm -it docker/surprise`).

The docs should be updated for this caveat since both `docker --version` and `docker run hello-world` is supposed to demonstrate that you've successfully set up Docker. Just know that you should use the `docker/surprise` image instead in such cases.

Comment: Well `docker run hello-world` should work if `docker --version` outputs normally.

Comment: it is displaying Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea

Comment: Try `docker run --rm -it docker/surprise` instead.

Answer (score 6):

This error implies your host machine's OS is not compatible with the OS docker image you are trying to pull. See [Windows container version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-20H2%2Cwindows-10-20H2)

For example, if you are running Windows 10 1809 on your host OS, you cannot pull `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1909`. However you can of course pull `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809`

e.g. `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809`

or `docker-compose up` with a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  myWin:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809
    networks:
      - myNet

networks:
  myNet:
    driver: nat
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's related to your actual PC, I mean you might be using an AMD processor.

In  my case, I am using **Windows Server 2016** on AMD processor. Docker gives Windows Server users another version called **Docker Enterprise Engine** (EE for short) and for Docker EE users who are on AMD, they should try this:

```
docker run hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016
```

Comment: amd64 is the name of an architecture, it does not mean that you are using an AMD processor. Intel processors also use amd64. Also Docker EE means Enterprise Edition, not Enterprise Engine.